# How to fix "There too many argument in this opreator"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, visual-studio-2017, operator-overloading

I build a new string class in C++ called `UString`, I think it should support `cin` and `cout`, so I want to overload `<<` and `>>` operator, but my Visual Studio told me that I put too many argument in that function.

What should I do?

My first code like this:

```
std::istream &operator>>(UString ustr)
{
    std::istream istr(nullptr);
    istr >> ustr.str;
    return istr;
}
```

I didn't got any error if I compile the class without use this function,but if I use it by: `cin>>ustr;`, the compiler told me that there is no match ver of this `>>` operator. So I searched it in Google and changed it like that:

```
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream& ostr, const UString ustr)
{
    ostr << ustr.str;
    return ostr;
}
```

But, the pre-check told me that there are too many arguments in it, it can not be compiled successfully also.

My IDE is `Visual Studio 2017`, C++ ver is set to `C++17`.

```
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream& ostr, const UString ustr)
{
    ostr << ustr.str;
    return ostr;
}
//>>
std::istream &operator>>(UString ustr)
{
    std::istream istr(nullptr);
    istr >> ustr.str;
    return istr;
}
```

After overloading, it should support use like this:

```
UString ustr;
cin>>ustr;
cout<<ustr<<endl;
```

Comment: Your `operator >>` needs to look just like your `operator <<`.  replace the `std::ostream& ostr` with `std::istream& istr`

Comment: I'm suspecting you have messed up operator definition as a member function and or as global function. Problem is that code doesn't have enough context to be sure. Please provide [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::istream&`>>` and `<<` operators are binary operators (they have two arguments). When you overload this operators you can make it either member function (inside your class) or free function.

Code `x >> y;` will be transformed either to `x.operator>>(y);` (in case of member function) or to `operator>>(x, y);` (in case of free function).

As you want to overload operator with left argument of type that you can't modify (stream) you should overload it as a free function.

```
class UString { ... };

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, UString& str) { ... }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Ustring& str) { ... }
```